# Как задать шаблон для имен веток, вроде topic/myfeature или bugfixes/myfeature?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow, source-tree

Добрый день, сейчас я работаю с `git` репозиторием, на котором ветки организованы в папки: фичи в папке `topic/myfeature`, багфиксы в папке `bugfixes/myfeature`.

Собственно вопрос такой, могу ли я сконфигурировать дефолтное имя вообще всех новых веток которые я создаю, используя сам `git` или инструментарий `sourcetree`? То есть я хочу чтобы когда я нажимаю "создать новую ветку" мне предлагалось автоматически создать ветку с названием `topic/*`.

То есть мне нужно предустановленное название ветки которую я создаю. Самой ветки, имя репозитория к этому отношения не имеет.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу метку git-flow. В описании метки можно найти ссылки на документацию и софт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы описываете - это расширение git-flow, вводящее высокоуровневые операции для управления потоком разработки. Судя по именованию - большинство разработчиков в вашей комманде использут/использовали именно его.

SourceTree умеет работать с этим расширением. По нажатию на кнопку "Git Flow" на тулбаре открывается диалог инициализации Git Flow:

[image: диалог инициализации Git Flow]

В нем вы можете указать названия веток для разработки и продашена, для фич, релизов, хотфиксов, ну и префиксы для тегов версий.

После инициализации, по нажатию на кнопку Git Flow будет показыватся диалог операций, позволяющий начинать и завершать работу над фичами, релизами, хотфиксами и т.д:

[image: Диалог операций GitFLow]

Comment: Благодарю, именно оно)

Comment: тогда так
http://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/

Comment: @username, ага спасибо, я это читал раньше, только в работе мне это не пригодилось, так что у меня в голове gitflow отложился как некий способ организации бранчинга, а что под это дело тулза есть я как-то и не подумал даже

Answer (score 1):

```
git remote -v
# View existing remotes
# origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)

git remote rename origin topic
# Change remote name from 'origin' to 'topic'

git remote -v
# Verify remote's new name
# topic  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
# topic  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

локальный конфиг хранится тут, если что

```
vim .git/config
```

Comment: возможно я непонятно написал. Мне не нужно переименовывать удаленный репозиторий. На удаленном репозитории есть папки. У папок есть имена типа topic/ bugs/ etc. Мне нужно создавать ветку котоаря будет называться topic/mysuperbranch чтобы я ее потом сразу пушил в topic/mysuperbrunch на удаленном репозитории. Если я сделаю как Вы написали, то это мою задачу не решит вообще никак =)

Comment: откройте гляньте конфиг

Comment: а вообще вот такое есть `git remote set-head topic mysuperbranch`
хотя я уже не уверен что Вам нужно

Comment: спасибо, мне уже ответили, gitflow мне было нужно)